# Destructor or Deconstructor with regards to OOP?

Tags: oop, terminology

In my daily life and while reading books I've seen the term destructor as well as deconstructor.

But what is the correct name for this method?

Comment: I hear deconstructor for the first time:)

Comment: In what context have you seen deconstructor?  I have never seen it before so I am really curious to what it relates to:  A language specific destructor, or something else?!!!

Comment: I read it in general object oriented programming books. I try to search it ;) But I don't think its such a bad term because it clearly shows the relation between constructor/destructor

Comment: I presume a deconstructor works along the principles laid out in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconstruction and so seeks to expose the fundamental contradictions in the concept of the object and its relation to the post-modern zeitgeist of metasyntactic possibilities inherent in society's oppression of artistic freedom. Or something like that.

Comment: Actually yes - it probably is a better term for a destructor.

Comment: "Deconstruct" is too delicate a term for most code I have handled. "Don't forget to bulldoze it when you're done!!"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is **destructor** used to cleanup the stuff when the object is about to die. It is called automatically if specified when object is going to be removed/die.

More Info:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destructor_%28computer_science%29

Answer (score 9):

Destructor if you are refering to OOP. Deconstructor when talking about
[World of Warcraft](http://www.wowwiki.com/XT-002_Deconstructor) ;-).

Comment: Deconstruct is a very powerful tool in a lot of languages, e.g. Scala, `val head::tail = List(1,2,3)`, es6: `const [head, ...tail] = [1,2,3]`

Comment: @UstamanSangat fwiw it's called [Structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) in c++. And afaik it's called destructuring in javascript.

Answer (score 7):

As others has explained already, a `destructor` is used to clean up an object.

There is a new feature in C# 7, which can be referred to as a `deconstructor`:

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public void Deconstruct(out string firstName, out string lastName)
    {
        firstName = FirstName;
        lastName = LastName;
    }
}

var person = new Person { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" };
var (localFirstName, localLastName) = person;
```

The more common names for this feature are `deconstruct method` or simply `deconstruction` but I found at least one instance on the [official msdn blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/) referring to it as a `deconstructor` (emphasis mine):

> It will be a common pattern to have constructors and **deconstructors** be “symmetric” in this way.

Comment: This kind of terminology also appears to be language-specific. For instance, in ES6 JavaScript [it's referred to as "destructuring"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Answer (score 5):

Destructor is the most common term (deconstructor sounds like local usage: I like it in a way, since it points out a symmetry with constructors).

But these things are to some extent language-specific, since different OO languagers have different models for the lifecycle of instances. Take C#, for instance, where [instead of destructors](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/oreilly/dotnet/news/programmingCsharp_0801.html) you have [finalizers](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/chandrahundigam/UnderstandingDestructors11192005021208AM/UnderstandingDestructors.aspx), which have weak execution guarantees, [supplemented](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/oreilly/dotnet/news/programmingCsharp_0801.html) by the language-supported `Dispose()` pattern which provides determinacy.

Answer (score 4):

"Destructor" is indeed the correct term. 
I have seen "deconstructor" in older books, and it appears that there was debate for a while over the correct term, but destructor appears to have won out.

As for the flippant answers about what wiki or WoW says about deconstruction: try looking up "destructor" in a standard dictionary. Apparently, it's a device for destroying an off-course airborne missile or launch vehicle.

Answer (score 3):

Destruct = Destroy

Deconstruct = Decompose (Reverse compose into pieces)

Put -tor then it's the executer of the verb.
So it's depend on the context you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I still remember the lecture that introduced concepts in Haskell when I first heard of the word "deconstructor". I first was confused because I thought of destructors but as it quickly turned out, they are different concepts. Haskell has no destructors but deconstructors. They are used to retrieve single data member fields that a structured value contains. They are basically member accessors but as functions.

I actually wondered about the word because I practically never found it elsewhere. Here I found an answer:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/168650/whats-the-proper-term-for-a-function-inverse-to-a-constructor-to-unwrap-a-val

Decomposer oder destructuring could be a good equivalent term and "destructuring" really is something that I commonly have heard of.